# В каком виде хранить возраст в базе?

Tags: php, mysql

Добрый день.

Не могу решить, в каком виде лучше всего будет хранить возраст пользователей в базе?
Если вписывать количество лет напрямую, через пару лет данные станут не актуальны. Тут лучше будет вписать год рождения и при выводе в профиль уже считать сколько там юзеру лет, но что-то не видел чтобы так делали. Как обычно хранят возраст (день рождения) пользователей в базе? И в каком виде? В явном (1986) или в количестве секунд от 1970-го?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так и хранить в виде даты рождения. Все, обычно, именно так и делают. Например, именно так сделано на этом сайте. В своем профиле пользователь, по желанию, водит дату рождения. А остальные видят расчетный возраст.

Answer (score 2):

> И в каком виде? В явном (1986) или в количестве секунд от 1970-го ?

В поле типа [date](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html).